# Upload a zip file with Post request using robot framework and REST

Tags: rest, file-upload, http-post, robotframework

Need help with this.
I'm trying to upload a zip file executing a POST request to a REST API. I'm using robotframework along with request library. After see some example I getting to nowhere.
Here is my code:

```
${DATA}= Get Binary File C:\\Users\\${USERNAME}\\data\\Lampadaires.zip 
${DATA}= Get File C:\\Users\\${USERNAME}\\data\\Lampadaires.zip encoding=CP437 
&{dictFiles} Create Dictionary file=${DATA} type=application/x-zip-compressed 
&{headers} Create Dictionary Content-Type=multipart/form-data accept=*/* 
Create Session session http://[test_url]docker.net:8080 headers=${headers}
${resp} Post Request session /rest/v1/organizations/${ORGANIZATION_ID}/upload files=${dictFiles}
Should Be Equal As Strings ${resp.status_code} 200
```

I want to execute the same request as this CURL

```
curl -X POST "http://[test_url]docker.net:8080/rest/v1/organizations/${ORGANIZATION_ID}/upload" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=C:\Users\${USERNAME}\data\Lampadaires.zip;type=application/x-zip-compressed"
```

Answer (score 1):

After some rechearch I was able to find a solution for uploading a zip file. 
First thing:
not need to set content type in the header because the request library do the job for you.
Second:
for the file to upload you need to create the dictionary with some specific configuration because along with the data you need to provide as well Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Lampadaires.zip" Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed in my case.
So using Get Binary File keyword is not enough.

This was my code in the end

```
Library    RequestsLibrary       
Library    Collections 
Library    OperatingSystem

***Variables***
${ORGANIZATION_ID}    1234
${ALIAS}    MyAlias
${MCS_URL}    http://test_url:8080
${FILE_UPLOAD_PATH}    C:\\Users\\Daryll\\Documents\\data\\Lampadaires.zip
***Test Cases***
Zip File Upload
   Create Session    ${ALIAS}    ${MCS_URL}
   &{headers}=    Create Dictionary    Accept=*/*
   &{fileParts}=    Create Dictionary
   Create Multi Part    ${fileParts}    file    ${FILE_UPLOAD_PATH}    application/x- 
   zip-compressed

   ${response}=    Post Request    ${ALIAS}    
   /rest/organizations/${ORGANIZATION_ID}/upload    files=${fileParts}    
   headers=${headers}

   Log    ${response.status_code}    console=${True}
   Log    ${response.json()}    console=${True}

*** Keywords ***
Create Multi Part    [Arguments]    ${addTo}    ${partName}     ${filePath}    
    ${contentType}    ${content}=${None}
    ${fileData}=    Run Keyword If    '''${content}''' != '''${None}'''    Set 
    Variable    ${content}
    ...            ELSE    Get Binary File    ${filePath}
    ${fileDir}    ${fileName}=    Split Path    ${filePath}
    ${partData}=    Create List    ${fileName}    ${fileData}    ${contentType}
    Set To Dictionary    ${addTo}    ${partName}=${partData}
```